# React setState array issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have this javascript code below:

```
const getProducts = () => {
        votationRef
            .child(moment().format('yyyy-MM-DD'))
            .once('value').then((snapshot) => {
                try {
                    var productsId = snapshot.val();
                    productsId.map((item) => {
                        productsRef
                            .child(item)
                            .once('value')
                            .then((snapshot) => {
                                setProducts([...products, snapshot.val()]);
                            })
                    })
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('ERROR', e.message)
                }
            })
    }
```

In short, the function `getProducts` is called with the `useEffect` hook before the DOM complete its loading.

This function has the task of retrieving the details of each product stored on my Firebase RT DB (by each `productsId`) and to put them into a state array (`setProducts`).

The final `products` array result is simply displayed as a "paragraph list" in my JSX. Here's the code:

```
products.map((item) => {
    return <p>{item.name}</p>
})
```

Could someone please explain to me why my React state `products`, at the end of the above procedure, contains only the details of the last product in my firebase "products" document node?

Currently my firebase "products" document node contains this data:

```
"products" : {
    "-MK-CnXnTYbyYm5eyYBK" : {
      "coverImg" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onebidup.appspot.com/o/images%2FcoverImages%2F32a01e12-e7a2-44df-ac62-5d5eac00d031.jpg?alt=media&token=7b9b8304-c0b1-4123-85fd-b0fe4096d3d0",
      "description" : "Audio che riempie la stanza - I cinque altoparlanti offrono bassi potenti, medi dinamici e alti nitidi",
      "maxVote" : 5,
      "name" : "Echo Studio - Altoparlante intelligente",
      "price" : "189.99"
    },
    "-MKFOYfuAdK8Fo4l-aiV" : {
      "coverImg" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onebidup.appspot.com/o/images%2FcoverImages%2F8e1edf42-562b-4a05-8180-b320968b1024.jpg?alt=media&token=ffad077c-014c-4a60-aab0-edb2cbe526f5",
      "description" : "La serie Q64 è una variante di colore silver della serie Q60 a cui aggiunge il telecomando Premium Metal One Remote e la tecnologia di controllo dell’immagine Ultimate UHD Dimming",
      "name" : "Samsung QE55Q64RATXZT Serie Q64R QLED Smart TV 55\", Ultra HD 4K, Wi-Fi, Silver, 2019",
      "price" : "669"
    },
    "-MKFOsBlMmFS5wnBk8jr" : {
      "coverImg" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onebidup.appspot.com/o/images%2FcoverImages%2Fa7247e86-b745-4806-8e93-1de733e4f698.jpg?alt=media&token=4b0adf1c-9a90-4da7-9c43-5db40d80ee76",
      "description" : "Splendidamente progettato e costruito per durare - elegante, pratico e affidabile",
      "name" : "Segway-Ninebot ES4 Monopattino Elettrico",
      "price" : "773"
    },
    "-MKFPAewl96EKp3noj2J" : {
      "coverImg" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onebidup.appspot.com/o/images%2FcoverImages%2F1943a11f-d1ee-4188-9aa9-af0d42466d11.jpg?alt=media&token=f6e1f9ae-7632-406e-acde-5554c45d5ee4",
      "description" : "Sony PS4 PRO PlayStation Gamma Chassis + PS Live Card 20€, 4K HDR, 1 TB [Esclusiva Amazon.it]",
      "name" : "Sony PS4 PRO PlayStation",
      "price" : "419"
    },
    "-MKFPY6pWSPGUfTGIUuH" : {
      "coverImg" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onebidup.appspot.com/o/images%2FcoverImages%2F0fccd324-e03e-4680-8553-688dd1be25bc.jpg?alt=media&token=c695e0af-d2d2-448e-9747-1aaa6910197f",
      "description" : "iRobot Roomba 981 Robot aspirapolvere WiFi, Power-Lifting, 2 spazzole in gomma multi-superficie, Adatto per peli, Tecnologia Dirt Detect, pulizia a 3 fasi, programmabile con app, Compatibile Alexa",
      "name" : "iRobot Roomba 981",
      "price" : "538.80"
    }
  }
```

Comment: `snapshot.val()` will return the above json ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `products` is an empty array, even after you call:

```
setProducts([...products, snapshot.val()])
```

To build upon the previous value you have to use the callback variant:

```
setProducts(products => [...products, snapshot.val()])
```

The main issue s that `setProducts` updates `products` on the next render. It doesn't affect the current value of `products`. By using a callback the new value is passed in and can then be used.

This behaviour is described in the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) documentation:

> #### Functional updates
>
> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value. Here’s an example of a counter component that uses both forms of `setState`:
>
> ```
> function Counter({initialCount}) {
>   const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
>   return (
>     <>
>       Count: {count}
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
>     </>
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> The ”+” and ”-” buttons use the functional form, because the updated value is based on the previous value. But the “Reset” button uses the normal form, because it always sets the count back to the initial value.
>
> If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.